# Issue with : "save picture as" in IE for an image retrieved from database via an image handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage that contains an aspImage control
When I retrive an image from database via an image handler I can show that image in the aspImage control ! BUT . . . the problem is when I right click on the image and click "save picture as" I get this error message : The file type being saved or retrieved has been blocked !
I wonder if this is an IE issue or something is wrong with my code ?! any help ?!

Here is my image handler code :

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string TableName=context.Session["TableToQuery"].ToString();
        string ID=context.Session["ID"].ToString();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM "+ TableName +" WHERE ID=" + ID, conn);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image"]);
        conn.Close();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the datalist in wich I show my image :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" RepeatColumns="1"
                            RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
                                    <tr style="width: 100%; height: 350px">
                                        <td valign="middle">
                                            <asp:Image ID="IMage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="width: 100%; height: 250px">
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDecoded" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="316px"
                                                Height="200px" Text='<%#Eval("DecodedString")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Your image handler is probably sending the wrong headers, but without a test url or sample code it's impossible to find the problem.

Comment: @AlfonsoML I added my source code ! I would be happy if you could help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending any headers declaring the MIME type of the contents, just a `context.Response.BinaryWrite`

At the very least you should add something like this before the BinaryWrite

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```